# In Black Swan how much seduction is real?

Tags: plot-explanation, black-swan

In the film Black Swan there are a number of scenes where Nina and Thomas Leroy have a more than professional relationship.  Are these real or are they part of her illness (in the same way as parts of her relationship with Lily).

There are three sections I can think of:

1. The kiss which gets her the part
2. The scene in the studio
3. The kiss during the performance

Do we have any evidence that any of these didn't happen?

ETA: The scene in the studio I mentioned earlier was where Thomas Leroy pretended to seduce her to get her to give the performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The kiss that gets her the part has to be real.  Otherwise, how does she get the part?  Furthermore, Thomas says that "he saw a bit of that earlier" in reference to it.

By the scene in the studio, you mean where Thomas is having sex with Lily, right?  Because that's Nina's imagination.  She's paranoid that Lily is using sex to get ahead of her, and when the whole set becomes all black, the music and mise-en-scene imply that her paranoia is starting to take over.

The kiss during the performance is real.  It's a part of her "performance" as a Black Swan, so the only way the kiss couldn't be real is if her entire performance was her imagination.

I think Black Swan is open to a lot of interpretations, but these are the answers that make the most sense to me.

Comment: The scene in the studio I mentioned earlier was where Thomas Leroy pretended to seduce her to get her to give the performance.